module javafx.graphics does not "opens com.sun.javafx.application" to unnamed module @2133814f
A am tryng to run a test with @ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class) and I keep geting this error
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static java.util.Map com.sun.javafx.application.ParametersImpl.params accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens com.sun.javafx.application" to unnamed module @2133814f
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:181)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:175)
    at org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ToolkitServiceImpl.cleanupParameters(ToolkitServiceImpl.java:177)
    at org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ToolkitServiceImpl.cleanupApplication(ToolkitServiceImpl.java:138)
    at org.testfx.api.FxToolkit.cleanupApplication(FxToolkit.java:178)
    at org.testfx.api.FxToolkit.cleanupAfterTest(FxToolkit.java:186)
    at org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension.afterEach(ApplicationExtension.java:87)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:261)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$14(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.CollectionUtils.forEachInReverseOrder(CollectionUtils.java:217)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:260)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:145)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

here is my code
package gui;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension;

@ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class)
public class AddTripTest {

    @Test
    void demo(){

    }
}

Im using intelij java 20 and maven
I just want to get rid of this error. if I get rid of @ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class) it does work but I need @ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class) to actualy write the test

That looks like you are missing module-info.java you need to put that to your main package folder and define what should be exported
module swaggerific {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.swing;

//////....
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific.animation;
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific.animation to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific.ui;
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific.ui to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific.data;
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific.data to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.component;
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.component to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.edit;
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.edit to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.textfx;
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.textfx to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.exception;
    opens com.mascix.swaggerific.ui.exception to javafx.fxml;
}

You can find full working example here. And you can find working example test code here. I will give the example code below too
package com.mascix.swaggerific;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.testfx.api.FxAssert;
import org.testfx.api.FxRobot;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.Start;
import org.testfx.matcher.control.LabeledMatchers;

@ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class)
class ClickableButtonTest_JUnit5Hamcrest {

    private Button button;

    /**
     * Will be called with {@code @Before} semantics, i. e. before each test method.
     *
     * @param stage - Will be injected by the test runner.
     */
    @Start
    private void start(Stage stage) {
        button = new Button("click me!");
        button.setId("myButton");
        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> button.setText("clicked!"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(button), 100, 100));
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param robot - Will be injected by the test runner.
     */
    @Test
    void should_contain_button_with_text(FxRobot robot) {
        FxAssert.verifyThat(button, LabeledMatchers.hasText("click me!"));
        // or (lookup by css id):
        FxAssert.verifyThat("#myButton", LabeledMatchers.hasText("click me!"));
        // or (lookup by css class):
        FxAssert.verifyThat(".button", LabeledMatchers.hasText("click me!"));
    }

    /**
     * @param robot - Will be injected by the test runner.
     */
    @Test
    void when_button_is_clicked_text_changes(FxRobot robot) {
        // when:
        robot.clickOn(".button");

        // then:
        FxAssert.verifyThat(button, LabeledMatchers.hasText("clicked!"));
        // or (lookup by css id):
        FxAssert.verifyThat("#myButton", LabeledMatchers.hasText("clicked!"));
        // or (lookup by css class):
        FxAssert.verifyThat(".button", LabeledMatchers.hasText("clicked!"));
    }
}

